# Why is Mini-Profiler, only showing "ExecuteStoreCommands" for the SQL text?

Tags: entity-framework-4, mvc-mini-profiler

I just hooked up MiniProfiler to my MVC3 project.  I am using EF4.0 and generating POCO classes for my entities.

If it matters, these generated ObjectContexts use ObjectSet<>.  I am also using NInject for IoC on the contexts.  (I had these in RequestScope, but I changed them to TransientScope to rule that issue out).

All of the profiling that I am seeing is showing "ExecuteStoreCommands" as the query.

Any ideas as to why "ExecuteStoreCommands" would be showing up instead of the SQL?  I see real sql in SQL Profiler that looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
...
```

Am I having trouble because I'm not on EF4.1/4.2/4.3?  Is it because I didn't use CodeFirst?  Is it the POCOs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm having trouble with the MiniProfiler library.  The serialization of the `SqlTiming` object (via FromJSON) saves the `FormattedCommandString` which only has a get method.  On deserialization, this meant that the `CommandString` and `FormattedCommandString` were both `null`.

The quick (hacky) fix before Deserialization was:

```
profilerString = profilerString.Replace("FormattedCommandString", "CommandString");
var profiler = MiniProfiler.FromJson(profilerString);
```